# Generator of translation for the hyperbolic plane?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

What is the generator of translation in the Beltrami-Klein model of the hyperbolic plane?

Comment: I've voted to close.  math.stackexchange.com is a more appropriate forum for your question. 

Comment: I've also voted to close.  The notion of "the generator of translation" also makes no sense, as r0b0t's answer below suggests.

Answer (score 3):

Hyperbolic plane is a homogeneous space $G/H$ where $G$ acts by isometries and so any reasonable defined `translation' is given by the natural left action of $G$. Decide what elements of $G$ will you call translations and then for any abstract generator $X\in\mathfrak{g}$ such that $\exp{tX}$ is translation, compose the natural left action with diffeomorphism of $G/H$ to your favorite model. Differentiate the resulting map at zero and you are done.

If I am not mistaken, this question is more suitable for math.SE.